# C language preprocessor behavior

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

There are different kind of macros in the **C** language, nested macro is one of them.

Considering a program with the following macro

```
#define HYPE(x,y) (SQUR(x)+SQUR(y))
#define SQUR(x)   (x*x)
```

Using this we can successfully compile to get the result.

As we all know the **C** preprocessor replaces all the occurrence of the identifiers with the replacement-string. Considering the above example I would like to know how many times the **C** preprocessor traverses the program to replace the macro with the replacement values. I assume it cannot be done in one go.

Comment: Sounds like homework, and sounds like it belongs on SO.

Comment: What would the result of SQUR(3+3) be?  (3+3*3+3)=15.  You want ((x)*(x)), except that is still poor because it evaluates the replacement twice.  Consider SQUR(random()).

Answer (score 1):

the replacement takes place, when "HYPE" is actually used. it is not expanded when the #define statement occurs.

eg:

```
1 #define FOO 1
2
3 void foo() {
4    printf("%d\n", FOO);
5 }
```

so the replacement takes place in line 5, and not in line 1. hence the answer to your question is: once.

Answer (score 0):

`A #define`'d macro invocation is expanded until there are no more terms to expand, except it doesn't recurse.  For example:

```
#define TIMES        *
#define factorial(n) ((n) == 0 ? 1 : (n) TIMES factorial((n)-1))
    // Doesn't actually work, don't use.
```

Suppose you say `factorial(2)`.  It will expand to `((2) == 0 ? 1 : (2) * factorial((2)-1))`.  Note that `factorial` is expanded, then `TIMES` is also expanded, but `factorial` isn't expanded again afterwards, as that would be recursion.

However, note that nesting (arguably a different type of "recursion") is in fact expanded multiple times in the same expression:

```
#define ADD(a,b)     ((a)+(b))
....
ADD(ADD(1,2),ADD(3,4)) // expands to ((((1)+(2)))+(((3)+(4))))
```